# How to write "http://www" in a comment without creating a link?

Tags: discussion, comments

I definitely need to know how to escape that in comments.

Comment: `http://www` - inline code with backticks?

Comment: @DonaldDuck Adding zero-width spaces in actual links is not something you should do. It breaks the link when copy-pasting it, without any visual indication of why it doesn't work. Someone might spend a long time trying to figure out why the link doesn't work, only to find out it has a zero-width space in it, or copy it to a code section breaking functionality and creating hard-to-troubleshoot problems.

Comment: [re: Erik, Donald] See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48270127/1663383

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a code block:

```
`http://www`
```

Since HTML does not work in comments, I don't think we have a better option. But this should be only used, if it is semantically part of code.

Is there any reason, you do not want to make it clickable? Maybe what you are trying to comment has the semantics of code.